# Unable to find any installed .NET Core SDKs issue

Tags: .net

I'm trying to learn C# Code but I keep getting this error saying *Unable to find any installed .NET Core SDKs issue*, no matter what I try.

I've re-installed .Net many times, and made sure it was the latest version, but I keep getting this error.

I installed dotnet from https://aka.ms/dotnet-download, and made sure that it is the correct one. My dotnet core does indeed exist in C:\Program Files\dotnet.

I'm trying to run this command on visual studio code in the terminal window in order to code C#

> ```
>   It was not possible to find any installed .NET Core SDKs
>   Did you mean to run .NET Core SDK commands? Install a .NET Core SDK from:
>      https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
> ```

Comment: did you install sdk? https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download

Comment: Please edit your question to include details on how you are installing, and what command or tool is giving the error you mention.

Comment: Updated @JoeSewell

Comment: You mention that `C:\Program Files\dotnet` exists, but does `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk` exist? If so, what versioned subdirectories are under it?

Comment: @JoeSewell sdk doesn't exist for some reason. All i see is
host,
shared,
swidtag,
dotnet,
LICENCE, and
ThirdPartyNotices.
Is there anything i did wrong?

Comment: When you went to download, and selected a version, did you select something from the second column (*Build apps - SDK*) or the third column (*Run apps - Runtime*)? The second column is for people making .NET Core apps, the third column is for people who just want to run .NET Core apps.

Comment: @JoeSewell I Installed the Run Apps option in the first collum. Thats what they told me to do in the tutorial. Do i download the 3rd one instead?

Comment: Yes, you must install from the column that says "SDK".

Comment: @JoeSewell Thank you so much, I guess the tutorial told me wrong. Been trying to figure this out for about 2 hours now.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. Tried an incredible amount of updates, installing mono-devel, mono-complete, changing project files and much more.

In the end the first comment to your question contained the answer for me on Ubuntu. And I just wanted to share it for anyone that might miss the comment.

Simply went to this link as said above:

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download

Navigated to Ubuntu 20.10:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu#2010-

Executed the scripts, closed and restarted code. Problem solved.

Hat tip to [@Nonik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6472007/nonik)

Comment: Great solution. Choosing the right Linux version on the doc.microsoft.com/... MATTERS!